# Интеграция symfony c 1C

Tags: php, 1с, symfony3, интеграция

Доброго времени суток, появилась задача интегрировать 1C управление торговлей 11,4 с сайтом на symfony.
Или есть возможность подключения к базе 1c из php?

P.S(ищу, но что то найти не могу :'( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для возможности подключения к базе 1С из php нужно смотреть на адаптер для MS SQL, думаю такое можно найти. Но нужно иметь ввиду, что:

1. Это очень "хрупкое" решение. Структура БД выглядит так как будто ее специально обфусцировали - таблицы называются, например, _Reference123, а поля _Fld123. После изменения конфигурации нет никаких гарантий что все останется точно таким же.
2. Это является нарушением лицензионного соглашения и в поддержке со стороны 1С в последующем может быть отказано.

Более корректным здесь было бы одно из следующих:

1. Реализовать REST веб-сервис на стороне 1С УТ. Можно использовать расширения конфигурации, если конфигурация находится на поддержке.
2. Использовать какой-нибудь MQ. Например Rabbit MQ + HTTP адаптер, написанный на Go. В этом случае необходимые изменения можно постить в MQ и уже нормально обрабатывать на стороне symfony.

Comment: Спасибо буду думать над решением, сейчас пришли к тому что делаем на битриксе сайт, и там уже интегрировать(